# Parsing logged-in website from webview with jsoup

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, jsoup

I've made an WebView application with javascript and user-prompt (dialog outside website, before webview loads) which I use to log in that website. Now I want to get some informations using jsoup, but problem is that jsoup gets informations from non-logged in homepage. For example, if I'm not logged in at website homepage does not have informations like Username, Messages etc. I want to get these informations using jsoup, but I can't since jsoup isn't actually reading same page as it's in webview. Is there any way I can somehow "connect" jsoup and webview so jsoup read pages as they are inside WebView? I need this to make android notifications about new messages...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute javascript to pass the HTML content that was loaded back to the Activity that contains it by registering a `JavascriptInterface`

You can create the interface in your Activity as a private inner class:

```
private class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void handleHtml(String html) {
         // Use jsoup on this String here to search for your content.
         Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

         // Now you can, for example, retrieve a div with id="username" here
         Element usernameDiv = doc.select("#username").first();
    }
}
```

Then, attach this to your WebView:

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HtmlHandler");
```

Finally, add a `WebViewClient` that will call this javascript method every time the page loading completes. You will have to determine when the user is logged in based on the content of the page at that time:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlHandler.handleHtml" +
                    "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to check if certain div is there on site using jsoup? I should connect jsoup to what? Can you please edit your question and explain more deeply about "handleHtml" part? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `handleHtml(String html)` is your callback at which time you will be passed a `String` that contains the full html content of the page. You can use JSoup as you normally would to parse this String and work with the result. I have edited my answer to show the first call to JSoup.

Comment: Now I get this error: 11-19 04:56:05.787      899-899/ba.gamers.gamersba I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'handleHTML'", source: http://www.mywebsite.com/ (1)
11-19 04:56:05.817      899-899/ba.gamers.gamersba I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source: http://www.mywebsite.com/ (1)

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the method using different cases. This is case sensitive, in the JavaScript string change handleHTML to handleHtml