# Accessing DOM Elements via WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

On Android.

I followed the steps on
[How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview)
When a page is loaded it logs out 'undefined' for document.

My SDK settings:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 22
```

code:

```
class JavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processContent(String aContent)
    {
        Log.i("js", aContent);
    }
}

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "INTERFACE");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);");
    }
});
myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```

Comment: Try out JSOUP for Android

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks for the tip, but this doesn't solve my problem since it would redownload the entire page. I need to parse the exact page that's loaded into my WebView.

Comment: You can use jsoup in conjunction with your WebView. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948087/parsing-logged-in-website-from-webview-with-jsoup should help if I understand your needs correctly.